# Safe to use `UIDocumentMenuViewController` without iCloud entitlement? Catch exception?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, icloud

Adding the iCloud entitlement to your app has negative consequences.

Unfortunately `UIDocumentMenuViewController` will throw an exception without it.

Is it possible to use these menus without an iCloud entitlement? In other words, by catching the exception, or something? We haven't tried so it may not be possible, but I wanted to ask.